# Including process execution time into shell prompt

Tags: bash, zsh

Is it possible to include the execution time of the just finished process - the output of the 'time' command - into the command prompt? We use zsh on linux and bash (msys) on windows machines so it would be nice to know how to do it in both.

Comment: show us what you have tried already, maybe we can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

For zsh you can try `$REPORTTIME` variable (search `man zshall` for it). It won't put time into the prompt, but it will echo time after each executed command (does not work in some cases). You can use `preexec` and `precmd` hooks and  and `$SECONDS` variable to get execution time (but it is not too precise):

```
function preexec() {
    typeset -gi CALCTIME=1
    typeset -gi CMDSTARTTIME=SECONDS
}
function precmd() {
    if (( CALCTIME )) ; then
        typeset -gi ETIME=SECONDS-CMDSTARTTIME
    fi
    typeset -gi CALCTIME=0
}
PS1='${ETIME} %'
```

(Note single quotes used in PS1 definition.)

Third approach will either force you to loose ability to change environment variables or will work only for single commands. It will also force you to write something hacky to view command output. This approach is “redefine accept-line zle widget to add `time` to the command executed”. I am not writing code here because it is has problems described above.

By the way, `$SECONDS` variable is also available in bash, though I do not know how to implement hooks there.